# Modify hyperlinks from different types of files (pptx;docx;xlsx) with VBA

Tags: vba, hyperlink, powerpoint, ms-word

I need to modify some hyperlinks from three types of files (word, power point and excel) using VBA. I've found enough examples so I have an almost working script, except the sub that deals with pptx files:

```
Sub pptxHyperLinkReplace(FileLoc As String) 'For power point
    Dim PPTapp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oHl As Hyperlink
    Dim sSearchFor As String
    Dim sReplaceWith As String
    Dim oSh As Shape
    sSearchFor = "http://europortal.ema.com/pws"
    If sSearchFor = "" Then Exit Sub End If
    sReplaceWith = "https://euro.sp.ema.com/BU/PWS/home"
    If sReplaceWith = "" Then Exit Sub End If
    On Error Resume Next
    Set PPTapp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    Set PPT = PPTapp.Presentations.Open(FileName:=FileLoc, _
        ReadOnly:=msoFalse, WithWindow:=msoTrue)
    PPT.Activate
    For Each oSl In PPT.Slides
        MsgBox (oSl.Hyperlinks.Count)
        For Each oHl In oSl.Hyperlinks
            oHl.Address = Replace(oHl.Address, sSearchFor, sReplaceWith)
            oHl.SubAddress = Replace(oHl.SubAddress, sSearchFor, sReplaceWith)
        Next    ' hyperlink
        ' fix OLE links and movie/sound linkes too
        For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
            If oSh.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Or oSh.Type = msoMedia Then
                oSh.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = Replace(oSh.LinkFormat.SourceFullName, _
                sSearchFor, sReplaceWith)
            End If
        Next 'shape
    Next    ' slide
    PPT.Save
    PPT.Close
    'Set PPT = Nothing
    PPTapp.Quit
    Set PPTapp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Everything works until this part: `For Each oHl In oSl.Hyperlinks`
The message box  `MsgBox (oSl.Hyperlinks.Count)` shows me the correct number of hyperlinks from each slide but it seems like oHl object remains empty, like the *For Each* is not working. I run this sub from a script in a word file (docm). If  I try the original script directly in the pptx file that I want to modify the hyperlinks it works with the exact same syntax.

So what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You need to try to understand a little bit what your code does, because you have a few places where errors can occur and they are hidden by the `On Error Resume Next` command, which tells Word (or PowerPoint) to ignore any errors and keep going. Try stepping through your code line by line (using F8) to see where the problems are. Another tip: use `Option Explicit` at the top of your code module to catch any undeclared variables.

Comment: Also, the `Replace`-line is overly complex, try changing it to: `oSh.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = sReplaceWith` if you want to change all links.

Comment: And to add to Olle's suggestions, are you certain that Word accepts Dim oSl as Slide and the other PowerPoint-specific Dim types?  It seems unlikely.  Try changing them to eg Dim oSl as PowerPoint.Slide and so on.

Comment: Thank you both for your input. It helped me find the problems. The problem was with declaration (it needed to be  `Dim oHl as PowerPoint.Hyperlink` ) . It did not recognized **oHl** As Hyperlink so it was just skipping the _For Each_ , and because I had the `On Error Resume Next` it did not show me any error. But I still don't understand why the `oSl As Slide` and `For Each oSl In PPT.Slides` worked fine with the incomplete syntax... Regarding the 'Replace' line , I use it because I need to change just the beginning part of some long link , not the whole link.

Answer (score 0):

I've made some progress. Now the script opens a filedialog window to select the main folder and will open  all word, power point , excel documents from that folder and all subfolders, replace parts of the hyperlinks and check if the new links are working in this documents , making an excel table with the broken links from all the files.

Now there is a problem with power point presentations when I run it on a SharePoint folder ("***Power point could not open the file***"-at this line= `If PPT Is Nothing Then Set PPT = PPTapp.Presentations.Open(fileName:=FileLoc, ReadOnly:=msoFalse, WithWindow:=msoFalse)` ). All other file types are handled correctly on SharePoint location ,and if I run this on a local folder even the PowerPoint are opened with no problem. 
So what I am doing wrong with power point files?

Here is the complete code:

```
'Replace hyperlinks(in word/ppt/excel) in selected folder and all subfolders
Sub HyperReplace()

ThisWorkbook.Activate
Cells(1, 1).Select

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
         .InitialFileName = "\\euro.blablabla.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\BU\PWS\home\ResourceManagement\Competences\Site Owners Documents\test\"
         .AllowMultiSelect = False
         If .Show <> -1 Then MsgBox "No folder selected! Exiting script.": Exit Sub
         folderpath = .SelectedItems(1)
         If (Left$(folderpath, 5) = "https") Then
         folderpath = Mid$(folderpath, 7, 32) & "@SSL/DavWWWRoot" & Mid$(folderpath, 39, Len(folderpath) - 32)
         folderpath = Replace(folderpath, "/", "\")
         End If
    End With

Call GetFilesInFolder(CStr(folderpath), True)
MsgBox "operation end, please view", vbInformation
End Sub

Sub GetFilesInFolder(SourceFolderName As String, Subfolders As Boolean)

'--- For Example:Folder Name= "D:\Folder Name\" and Flag as Yes or No

Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim SourceFolder As Scripting.Folder, SubFolder As Scripting.Folder
Dim FileItem As Scripting.File
Dim fileName As String


    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolderName)

    '--- This is for displaying, whereever you want can be configured


    For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files
     fileName = FileItem.Path
             If (Right$(fileName, 4) = "pptx" Or Right$(fileName, 3) = "ppt") Then
        pptxHyperLinkReplace (fileName)
        ElseIf (Right$(fileName, 4) = "docx" Or Right$(fileName, 3) = "doc") Then
        ReplaceWordHyperlinks (fileName)
        ElseIf (Right$(fileName, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right$(fileName, 4) = "xls") Then
        ExcelHyperLinkChange (fileName)
        'Else: MsgBox ("Noo ,îi bai!")
        End If

    Next FileItem

    '--- This is the Function to go each and Every Folder and get the Files. This is a Nested-Function Calling.

    If Subfolders = True Then
        For Each SubFolder In SourceFolder.Subfolders
        Call GetFilesInFolder(SubFolder.Path, True)
        Next SubFolder
    End If

    Set FileItem = Nothing
    Set SourceFolder = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing
End Sub
`

Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)


Sub MakeExcelBrokenLinksList(Filelocation As String, HLink As String, Optional ByVal NoBrokenLinks As Integer, Optional ByVal NoGoodLinks As Integer, Optional ByVal WLinks As Boolean = False)

ThisWorkbook.Activate

            Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, 1).Select
            ActiveCell.Value = Filelocation
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
            ActiveCell.Value = HLink

If WLinks = True Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 8
            Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Select
            ActiveCell.Value = NoGoodLinks
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
            ActiveCell.Value = NoBrokenLinks
            Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, 1).Select
            End If
End Sub

'For word
Sub ReplaceWordHyperlinks(FileLoc As String)
    Dim WordApp As Word.Application
    Dim Doc As Word.Document
    Dim HL As Word.Hyperlink

    Dim target As String
    Dim repl As String
    Dim DocBrokenLinks As Integer

   ' target = InputBox("Find address", "Replace Hyperlink")
   target = "http://europortal.blabalabla.com/pws"
    If Len(target) = 0 Then Exit Sub
   ' repl = InputBox("Replace address", "Replace Hyperlink")
   repl = "https://euro.sp.ema.blabalabla.com/BU/PWS/home"
    If Len(repl) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    DocBrokenLinks = 0

    If WordApp Is Nothing Then Set WordApp = New Word.Application
    If Doc Is Nothing Then Set Doc = Documents.Open(fileName:=FileLoc, Visible:=False)
    Doc.Activate


    For Each HL In Doc.Hyperlinks

     If (Len(HL.Address) > 248) Then
            Call MakeExcelBrokenLinksList(FileLoc, HL.Address)
            HL.Address = Left(HL.Address, 248)
         End If 'make sure that replaced link not exceeding max size of string

        With HL
            If InStr(LCase(.Address), LCase(target)) _
            Or InStr(LCase(.TextToDisplay), LCase(target)) Then
                .Address = Replace(.Address, target, repl)
                .TextToDisplay = Replace(.TextToDisplay, target, repl)
                .ScreenTip = Replace(.ScreenTip, target, repl)
                .Range.Fields.Update
            End If

        End With


        'Test if hyperlink is working
      If IsURLGood(HL.Address) = False Then
            Call MakeExcelBrokenLinksList(FileLoc, HL.Address)
            DocBrokenLinks = DocBrokenLinks + 1
      End If
      Sleep (250)
        'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")) 'only on excel
    Next 'hyperlink

    Call MakeExcelBrokenLinksList(Doc.Name, "TOTAL Hyperlinks: ", DocBrokenLinks, Doc.Hyperlinks.Count - DocBrokenLinks, True)

    Doc.Save
    'ActiveWindow.Close
    Doc.Close
    Set Doc = Nothing
    WordApp.Quit
    Set WordApp = Nothing

End Sub

'For power point

Sub pptxHyperLinkReplace(FileLoc As String)

    Dim PPTapp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim PPT As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim oSl As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim oHl As PowerPoint.Hyperlink
    Dim oSh As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim sSearchFor As String
    Dim sReplaceWith As String
    Dim PptBrokenLinks As Integer
    Dim PptLinks As Integer

    sSearchFor = "http://europortal.ema.blababal.com/pws"
    If sSearchFor = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    sReplaceWith = "https://euro.sp.ema.blababal.com/BU/PWS/home"
    If sReplaceWith = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    PptBrokenLinks = 0

    If PPTapp Is Nothing Then Set PPTapp = New PowerPoint.Application
    If PPT Is Nothing Then Set PPT = PPTapp.Presentations.Open(fileName:=FileLoc, ReadOnly:=msoFalse, WithWindow:=msoFalse)

    For Each oSl In PPT.Slides
        For Each oHl In oSl.Hyperlinks

         If (Len(oHl.Address) > 248) Then
            Call MakeExcelBrokenLinksList(FileLoc, oHl.Address)
            oHl.Address = Left(oHl.Address, 248)
         End If 'replaced link not exceeding max size of string

            oHl.Address = Replace(oHl.Address, sSearchFor, sReplaceWith)
            oHl.SubAddress = Replace(oHl.SubAddress, sSearchFor, sReplaceWith)

         'Test if hyperlink is working
            If IsURLGood(oHl.Address) = False Then
            Call MakeExcelBrokenLinksList(FileLoc, HL.Address)
            PptBrokenLinks = PptBrokenLinks + 1
            End If
            Sleep (250)

        Next    ' hyperlink
        PptLinks = PptLinks + oSl.Hyperlinks.Count

        ' fix OLE links and movie/sound linkes too
      '  For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
       '    If oSh.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject _
         '   Or oSh.Type = msoMedia Then
        '      oSh.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = Replace(oSh.LinkFormat.SourceFullName, sSearchFor, sReplaceWith)
        '   End If
      ' Next 'shape

    Next    ' slide

 Call MakeExcelBrokenLinksList(PPT.Name, "TOTAL Hyperlinks: ", PptBrokenLinks, PptLinks - PptBrokenLinks, True)

PPT.Save
PPT.Close
Set PPT = Nothing
PPTapp.Quit
Set PPTapp = Nothing

End Sub


'For excel

Sub ExcelHyperLinkChange(FileLoc As String)
    Dim XlSXapp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlsxBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlsxSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim oHl As Excel.Hyperlink
    Dim sSearchFor As String
    Dim sReplaceWith As String
    Dim ExcelBrokenLinks As Integer
    Dim ExcelLinks As Integer

    sSearchFor = "http://europortal.ema.blababal.com/pws"
    If sSearchFor = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    sReplaceWith = "https://euro.sp.ema.blababal.com/BU/PWS/home"
    If sReplaceWith = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ExcelBrokenLinks = 0

    If XlSXapp Is Nothing Then Set XlSXapp = New Excel.Application
    If xlsxBook Is Nothing Then Set xlsxBook = XlSXapp.Workbooks.Open(fileName:=FileLoc, ReadOnly:=msoFalse)

    For Each xlsxSheet In xlsxBook.Worksheets

        For Each oHl In xlsxSheet.Hyperlinks
            If (Len(oHl.Address) > 248) Then
            Call MakeExcelBrokenLinksList(FileLoc, oHl.Address)
            oHl.Address = Left(oHl.Address, 248)
            End If 'replaced link not exceeding max size of string

            oHl.Address = Replace(oHl.Address, sSearchFor, sReplaceWith)
            oHl.TextToDisplay = Replace(oHl.TextToDisplay, sSearchFor, sReplaceWith)

        'Test if hyperlink is working
            If IsURLGood(oHl.Address) = False Then
            Call MakeExcelBrokenLinksList(FileLoc, oHl.Address)
            ExcelBrokenLinks = ExcelBrokenLinks + 1
            End If 'link is working
            Sleep (250)

        Next    ' hyperlink
        ExcelLinks = ExcelLinks + xlsxSheet.Hyperlinks.Count

    Next xlsxSheet   ' sheet

Call MakeExcelBrokenLinksList(xlsxBook.Name, "TOTAL Hyperlinks: ", ExcelBrokenLinks, ExcelLinks - ExcelBrokenLinks, True)

xlsxBook.Save
xlsxBook.Close
Set xlsxBook = Nothing
XlSXapp.Quit
Set XlSXapp = Nothing
End Sub


Private Function IsURLGood(url As String) As Boolean
    ' Test the URL to see if it is good
    Dim request As New WinHttpRequest

    On Error GoTo IsURLGoodError
    If ((Len(url) > 1) And (Left(url, 4) <> "mail")) Then
    request.Open "GET", url
    request.Send
    If (request.Status = 200 Or request.Status = 401) Then
      IsURLGood = True
    Else
      IsURLGood = False
    End If
    Else: IsURLGood = True
    End If ' link is not empty
    Exit Function
IsURLGoodError:
        IsURLGood = False
End Function
```